# Is toolbar's logo icon clickable?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, toolbar, android-5.0-lollipop

i have used toolbar so now i want to apply click event over logo icon how can i get this event?

here is some coding stuff that i have done

```
Toolbar toolbar = null;
toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.actionToolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
setTitle(null);
toolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.back);
toolbar.setNavigationContentDescription("BACK");
toolbar.setLogo(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
toolbar.setLogoDescription("LOGO");

toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Nav", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});
```

Here i have set navigation icon and logo icon so now i want logo icon's click event, how it is possible?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You need to get first reference of it

```
View logoView = getToolbarLogoView(toolbar);
logoView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        //logo clicked
    }
});
```

Using content description we can get `View` reference. See the comments inline.

```
public static View getToolbarLogoIcon(Toolbar toolbar){
        //check if contentDescription previously was set
        boolean hadContentDescription = android.text.TextUtils.isEmpty(toolbar.getLogoDescription());
        String contentDescription = String.valueOf(!hadContentDescription ? toolbar.getLogoDescription() : "logoContentDescription");
        toolbar.setLogoDescription(contentDescription);
        ArrayList<View> potentialViews = new ArrayList<View>();
        //find the view based on it's content description, set programatically or with android:contentDescription
        toolbar.findViewsWithText(potentialViews,contentDescription, View.FIND_VIEWS_WITH_CONTENT_DESCRIPTION);
        //Nav icon is always instantiated at this point because calling setLogoDescription ensures its existence 
        View logoIcon = null;
        if(potentialViews.size() > 0){
            logoIcon = potentialViews.get(0);
        }
        //Clear content description if not previously present
        if(hadContentDescription)
            toolbar.setLogoDescription(null);
        return logoIcon;
    }
```

Comment: what is getLogoContentDescription / setLogoContentDescription

Comment: @MinaGabriel I have edited my answer. It should be getLogoDescription and setLogoDescription. Sorry.

Comment: Working ,but a bit hacking solution

Answer (score 14):

I was asking myself the same question and came across this. 
I took a similar approach to Nikola Despotoski but with a different implementation.

Instead of the method, what I did was:

```
// Set drawable
toolbar.setLogo(ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.logo));

// Find logo
View view = toolbar.getChildAt(1);
view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
      // Perform actions
    }
  });
```

Slightly hack-ish, but will come back review it a bit later. Sharing for discussion purposes.

Comment: Thanks for that. for me childAt(0) is the logo. child 1 is the title

Comment: This works for me, but I found the index would change, it could either be 0 or 1. I'm not sure what the difference was between the activities though.

Comment: The difference is the order in which the logo is turned on and the title is turned on. It has hidden elements which are added to the viewgroup when they are enabled, which means the 0th element is the one turned on first.

Answer (score 1):

Long-click event behavior for the appcompat:V7 ActionBar's logo view (ImageView)

```
    ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.setLogo(R.drawable.logo_vjet);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
    actionBar.setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(true);
    //find ActionBar View(ToolBar)
    View view = getWindow().getDecorView().findViewById(android.support.v7.appcompat.R.id.action_bar);
    if(view != null && view instanceof Toolbar){
        try {
            //find ImageView mLogoView; in Toolbar using reflect
            Field logoView = view.getClass().getDeclaredField("mLogoView");
            logoView.setAccessible(true);
            ImageView logoImageVIew = (ImageView) logoView.get(view);
            if(logoImageVIew != null){
                logoImageVIew.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                        //do something
                        return false;
                    }
                });
            }
        } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

tested only android 7.0

Comment: Please, edit the answer and add the code intention or a little explanation of the idea.