# How to set actionbar's logo click event in android app?

Tags: android

When I click to logo of application it will not redirect to my homepage . I tried a lot of codes.

I want to click on my logo and to be redirected to my homepage.

Here is my code:

```
getSupportActionBar().setLogo(R.mipmap.ic_launcher); //set the logo
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(true);

...

public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.home) {
        webViewPlaceholder.loadUrl("https:www.google.com");
    }
}
```

Comment: Try to use `android.R.id.home`.

Comment: Logo is not home.  You use setHomeAsUpEnabled and android.R.id home to handle clicks on the icon, not logo.  To handle clicks on the logo, see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28136087/is-toolbars-logo-icon-clickable)

Comment: Sir, i want to click that logo .. is there any event for that??

Comment: i m not using the custom actionbar . . is it possible to logo onclick event .
android.support.v7.appcompat

Comment: You can use the following code to set the back button on the onCreate method: ActionBar actionbar = getSupportActionBar();
        if(actionbar != null) {
            actionbar.setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.back_button);
            actionbar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        }                                                                                                                  Then you can check for android.R.id.home in onOptionsItemSelected.